# Minimize difference between norms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

I want to minimize the difference between two norms, for $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $M, N \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. $||\cdot||$ is the $L_2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$: $||x|| = \sqrt{ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2 } $

$ h^* = \displaystyle\arg\min_{||h|| = 1} \Big\{ ||Mh|| - ||Nh|| \Big\}$

Is there a way to find an expression for $h^*$ depending on $M$ and $N$ ?

All the references that I have found deal with, either the difference in the norm, like $||N - Mh||$ or the weights of the norms are positive like $||Mh|| + w||Nh|| \quad \text{with} \; w > 0$.
So they are not relevant, unless there is a way to transform my problem in something more classic ?

Comment: Clarification: Do you really want the min of that quantity or its absolute value? And are you using the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the post. I am interested in finding the minimizer $h^*$, and the bracket can take a negative value. For the norm, it is the classic norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It would be so much easier if you replaced $\|Mh\|-\|Nh\|$ with $\|Mh\|^2-\|Nh\|^2$. Otherwise, I'm afraid it might be difficult (if possible) to find a closed-form solution.

Comment: What would you do with the square norms ? Because maybe that method can still work or be adapted to my case. And yes otherwise, it looks like a difference of convex functions optimization problem which are numerically solved with DC programming, but not analytically.